# I am getting an error [Makefile:324: install-libLTLIBRARIES] and [Makefile:514: install-am] during make install in my Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, make, libraries, makefile

This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by libmfile configure 1.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.61.  Invocation command line was `./configure`

```
## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = lazyquercus
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 6.2.0-26-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/lazyquercus/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1972: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2028: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2039: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2082: result: yes
configure:2110: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2149: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:2162: checking for gawk
configure:2178: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2189: result: gawk
configure:2200: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2221: result: yes
configure:2631: checking for gcc
configure:2647: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:2658: result: gcc
configure:2896: checking for C compiler version
configure:2903: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2906: $? = 0
configure:2913: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 
configure:2916: $? = 0
configure:2923: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2926: $? = 1
configure:2949: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2976: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:2979: $? = 0
configure:3017: result: a.out
configure:3034: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3044: ./a.out
configure:3047: $? = 0
configure:3064: result: yes
configure:3071: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3073: result: no
configure:3076: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3083: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3086: $? = 0
configure:3110: result: 
configure:3116: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3142: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:3145: $? = 0
configure:3168: result: o
configure:3172: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:3201: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:3207: $? = 0
configure:3224: result: yes
configure:3229: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:3259: gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:3265: $? = 0
configure:3364: result: yes
configure:3381: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:3455: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:3461: $? = 0
configure:3484: result: none needed
configure:3513: checking for style of include used by make
configure:3541: result: GNU
configure:3566: checking dependency style of gcc
configure:3657: result: gcc3
configure:3674: checking dependency style of gcc
configure:3765: result: gcc3
configure:3793: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3849: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:3897: checking build system type
configure:3915: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3937: checking host system type
configure:3952: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3974: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:4053: result: /usr/bin/sed
configure:4071: checking for grep that handles long lines and -e
configure:4145: result: /usr/bin/grep
configure:4150: checking for egrep
configure:4228: result: /usr/bin/grep -E
configure:4233: checking for fgrep
configure:4311: result: /usr/bin/grep -F
configure:4346: checking for ld used by gcc
configure:4413: result: /usr/bin/ld
configure:4422: checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld
configure:4437: result: yes
configure:4449: checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)
configure:4498: result: /usr/bin/nm -B
configure:4620: checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface
configure:4627: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:4630: /usr/bin/nm -B "conftest.o"
configure:4633: output
0000000000000000 B some_variable
configure:4640: result: BSD nm
configure:4643: checking whether ln -s works
configure:4647: result: yes
configure:4655: checking the maximum length of command line arguments
configure:4775: result: 1572864
configure:4792: checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs
configure:4802: result: yes
configure:4806: checking whether the shell understands "+="
configure:4812: result: yes
configure:4847: checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files
configure:4854: result: -r
configure:4881: checking how to recognize dependent libraries
configure:5071: result: pass_all
configure:5131: checking for ar
configure:5147: found /usr/bin/ar
configure:5158: result: ar
configure:5240: checking for strip
configure:5256: found /usr/bin/strip
configure:5267: result: strip
configure:5343: checking for ranlib
configure:5359: found /usr/bin/ranlib
configure:5370: result: ranlib
configure:5464: checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object
configure:5582: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:5585: $? = 0
configure:5589: /usr/bin/nm -B conftest.o \| sed -n -e 's/^.*[   ]\([ABCDGIRSTW][ABCDGIRSTW]*\)[     ][  ]*\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)$/\1 \2 \2/p' \> conftest.nm
configure:5592: $? = 0
configure:5646: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c conftstm.o >&5
configure:5649: $? = 0
configure:5687: result: ok
configure:5783: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:5786: $? = 0
configure:6566: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:6606: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:6612: $? = 0
configure:6643: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:10:10: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
   10 | #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:6649: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libmfile"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libmfile"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libmfile 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "ralf.schulze@ikp.uni-koeln.de"
| #define PACKAGE "libmfile"
| #define VERSION "1.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:6682: result: gcc -E
configure:6711: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:6717: $? = 0
configure:6748: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:10:10: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
   10 | #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:6754: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libmfile"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libmfile"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libmfile 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "ralf.schulze@ikp.uni-koeln.de"
| #define PACKAGE "libmfile"
| #define VERSION "1.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:6792: checking for ANSI C header files
configure:6822: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:6828: $? = 0
configure:6927: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
configure:6930: $? = 0
configure:6936: ./conftest
configure:6939: $? = 0
configure:6956: result: yes
configure:6980: checking for sys/types.h
configure:7001: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7007: $? = 0
configure:7023: result: yes
configure:6980: checking for sys/stat.h
configure:7001: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7007: $? = 0
configure:7023: result: yes
configure:6980: checking for stdlib.h
configure:7001: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7007: $? = 0
configure:7023: result: yes
configure:6980: checking for string.h
configure:7001: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7007: $? = 0
configure:7023: result: yes
configure:6980: checking for memory.h
configure:7001: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7007: $? = 0
configure:7023: result: yes
configure:6980: checking for strings.h
configure:7001: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7007: $? = 0
configure:7023: result: yes
configure:6980: checking for inttypes.h
configure:7001: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7007: $? = 0
configure:7023: result: yes
configure:6980: checking for stdint.h
configure:7001: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7007: $? = 0
configure:7023: result: yes
configure:6980: checking for unistd.h
configure:7001: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7007: $? = 0
configure:7023: result: yes
configure:7039: checking for dlfcn.h
configure:7060: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7066: $? = 0
configure:7082: result: yes
configure:7266: checking for objdir
configure:7281: result: .libs
configure:7577: checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions
configure:7595: gcc -c -g -O2  -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions conftest.c >&5
cc1: warning: command-line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/D/ObjC++ but not for C
configure:7599: $? = 0
configure:7612: result: no
configure:7632: checking for gcc option to produce PIC
configure:7889: result: -fPIC -DPIC
configure:7901: checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works
configure:7919: gcc -c -g -O2  -fPIC -DPIC -DPIC conftest.c >&5
configure:7923: $? = 0
configure:7936: result: yes
configure:7960: checking if gcc static flag -static works
configure:7988: result: yes
configure:8003: checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o
configure:8024: gcc -c -g -O2  -o out/conftest2.o conftest.c >&5
configure:8028: $? = 0
configure:8050: result: yes
configure:8058: checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o
configure:8105: result: yes
configure:8138: checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries
configure:9193: result: yes
configure:9230: checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in
configure:9235: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:9238: $? = 0
configure:9253: gcc -shared conftest.o  -v -Wl,-soname -Wl,conftest -o conftest 2\>\&1 \| /usr/bin/grep  -lc  \>/dev/null 2\>\&1
configure:9256: $? = 0
configure:9268: result: no
configure:9432: checking dynamic linker characteristics
configure:9875: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/foo conftest.c  >&5
configure:9881: $? = 0
configure:10123: result: GNU/Linux ld.so
configure:10225: checking how to hardcode library paths into programs
configure:10250: result: immediate
configure:11063: checking whether stripping libraries is possible
configure:11068: result: yes
configure:11103: checking if libtool supports shared libraries
configure:11105: result: yes
configure:11108: checking whether to build shared libraries
configure:11129: result: yes
configure:11132: checking whether to build static libraries
configure:11136: result: yes
configure:11176: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99
configure:11335: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:11341: $? = 0
configure:11364: result: none needed
configure:11501: checking for gcc option to accept ISO Standard C
configure:11510: result: none needed
configure:11544: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:26:1: warning: 'visibility' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
   26 | void __attribute__ ((visibility("hidden"))) foo(void) { retu
      | ^~~~
conftest.c: In function 'foo':
conftest.c:26:57: error: unknown type name 'retu'
   26 | void __attribute__ ((visibility("hidden"))) foo(void) { retu
      |                                                         ^~~~
conftest.c:27:4: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before numeric constant
   27 | rn 1; };
      |    ^
configure:11550: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libmfile"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libmfile"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libmfile 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "ralf.schulze@ikp.uni-koeln.de"
| #define PACKAGE "libmfile"
| #define VERSION "1.0"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| void __attribute__ ((visibility("hidden"))) foo(void) { retu
| rn 1; };
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:11575: checking for an ANSI C-conforming const
configure:11650: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:11656: $? = 0
configure:11671: result: yes
configure:11683: checking whether byte ordering is bigendian
configure:11716: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:11722: $? = 0
configure:11754: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:29:2: error: unknown type name 'not'; did you mean 'ino_t'?
   29 |  not big endian
      |  ^~~
      |  ino_t
conftest.c:29:10: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'endian'
   29 |  not big endian
      |          ^~~~~~
configure:11760: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libmfile"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libmfile"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libmfile 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "ralf.schulze@ikp.uni-koeln.de"
| #define PACKAGE "libmfile"
| #define VERSION "1.0"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <sys/types.h>
| #include <sys/param.h>
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| #if BYTE_ORDER != BIG_ENDIAN
|  not big endian
| #endif
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:11900: result: no
configure:11927: checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together
configure:11962: gcc -c conftest.c -o conftest2.o >&5
configure:11965: $? = 0
configure:11971: gcc -c conftest.c -o conftest2.o >&5
configure:11974: $? = 0
configure:11985: cc -c conftest.c >&5
configure:11988: $? = 0
configure:11996: cc -c conftest.c -o conftest2.o >&5
configure:11999: $? = 0
configure:12005: cc -c conftest.c -o conftest2.o >&5
configure:12008: $? = 0
configure:12026: result: yes
configure:12274: creating ./config.status

## ---------------------- ##
## Running config.status. ##
## ---------------------- ##

This file was extended by libmfile config.status 1.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.61.  Invocation command line was

  CONFIG_FILES    = 
  CONFIG_HEADERS  = 
  CONFIG_LINKS    = 
  CONFIG_COMMANDS = 
  $ ./config.status 

on lazyquercus

config.status:853: creating Makefile
config.status:853: creating man/Makefile
config.status:853: creating src/Makefile
config.status:853: creating test/Makefile
config.status:853: creating src/config.h
config.status:1082: src/config.h is unchanged
config.status:1129: executing depfiles commands
config.status:1129: executing libtool commands

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_c_bigendian=no
ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_c_const=yes
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_header_dlfcn_h=yes
ac_cv_header_inttypes_h=yes
ac_cv_header_memory_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdc=yes
ac_cv_header_stdint_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdlib_h=yes
ac_cv_header_string_h=yes
ac_cv_header_strings_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_stat_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_types_h=yes
ac_cv_header_unistd_h=yes
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_path_EGREP='/usr/bin/grep -E'
ac_cv_path_FGREP='/usr/bin/grep -F'
ac_cv_path_GREP=/usr/bin/grep
ac_cv_path_SED=/usr/bin/sed
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_CPP='gcc -E'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_AR=ar
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_RANLIB=ranlib
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_STRIP=strip
ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=
ac_cv_prog_cc_c99=
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_cc_gcc_c_o=yes
ac_cv_prog_cc_stdc=
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_CC_dependencies_compiler_type=gcc3
lt_cv_deplibs_check_method=pass_all
lt_cv_file_magic_cmd='$MAGIC_CMD'
lt_cv_file_magic_test_file=
lt_cv_ld_reload_flag=-r
lt_cv_nm_interface='BSD nm'
lt_cv_objdir=.libs
lt_cv_path_LD=/usr/bin/ld
lt_cv_path_NM='/usr/bin/nm -B'
lt_cv_prog_compiler_c_o=yes
lt_cv_prog_compiler_pic_works=yes
lt_cv_prog_compiler_rtti_exceptions=no
lt_cv_prog_compiler_static_works=yes
lt_cv_prog_gnu_ld=yes
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_pipe='sed -n -e '\''s/^.*[   ]\([ABCDGIRSTW][ABCDGIRSTW]*\)[     ][  ]*\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)$/\1 \2 \2/p'\'''
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_c_name_address='sed -n -e '\''s/^: \([^ ]*\) $/  {\"\1\", (void *) 0},/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[ABCDGIRSTW]* \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)$/  {"\2", (void *) \&\2},/p'\'''
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_c_name_address_lib_prefix='sed -n -e '\''s/^: \([^ ]*\) $/  {\"\1\", (void *) 0},/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[ABCDGIRSTW]* \([^ ]*\) \(lib[^ ]*\)$/  {"\2", (void *) \&\2},/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[ABCDGIRSTW]* \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)$/  {"lib\2", (void *) \&\2},/p'\'''
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_cdecl='sed -n -e '\''s/^T .* \(.*\)$/extern int \1();/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[ABCDGIRSTW]* .* \(.*\)$/extern char \1;/p'\'''
lt_cv_sys_max_cmd_len=1572864

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/lazyquercus/Downloads/libmfile-1.0.7/build-aux/missing --run aclocal-1.10'
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /home/lazyquercus/Downloads/libmfile-1.0.7/build-aux/missing --run tar'
AR='ar'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/lazyquercus/Downloads/libmfile-1.0.7/build-aux/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/lazyquercus/Downloads/libmfile-1.0.7/build-aux/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/lazyquercus/Downloads/libmfile-1.0.7/build-aux/missing --run automake-1.10'
AWK='gawk'
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE='depmode=gcc3'
CFLAGS='-g -O2'
CPP='gcc -E'
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS='-DHAVE_CONFIG_H'
DEPDIR='.deps'
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='/usr/bin/grep -E'
EXEEXT=''
FGREP='/usr/bin/grep -F'
FVISIBILITY=''
GENERIC_LIBRARY_VERSION='1:5:1'
GENERIC_RELEASE='1.0'
GENERIC_VERSION='1.0.7'
GREP='/usr/bin/grep'
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD='/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL='$(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool'
LIPO=''
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/lazyquercus/Downloads/libmfile-1.0.7/build-aux/missing --run makeinfo'
NM='/usr/bin/nm -B'
NMEDIT=''
OBJEXT='o'
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='libmfile'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='ralf.schulze@ikp.uni-koeln.de'
PACKAGE_NAME='libmfile'
PACKAGE_STRING='libmfile 1.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='libmfile'
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB='ranlib'
SED='/usr/bin/sed'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP='strip'
VERSION='1.0.7'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE='#'
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='${prefix}'
host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='$(SHELL) /home/lazyquercus/Downloads/libmfile-1.0.7/build-aux/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
lt_ECHO='echo'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr/local'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME "libmfile"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libmfile"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "libmfile 1.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "ralf.schulze@ikp.uni-koeln.de"
#define PACKAGE "libmfile"
#define VERSION "1.0"
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
#define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
#define LOWENDIAN 1

configure: exit 0
```

Comment: What software exactly are you trying to build, and where did you obtain it?